# Web API does not serialize bool return type as a json boolean value

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, boolean

I have this ASP.NET Web API method :

```
[HttpGet]
public bool IsCodeValid(string code)
{
    return db.Usagers.Any(u => u.CodeAcces == code);
}
```

I am calling this Web API method from Angularjs's $http.get method :

```
return $http.get("/lewis/production/clockin/iscodevalid?code=" + code);
```

This is the result :

```
[object Object]{config: Object {...}, data: "false", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

Look at the *data* property, which is "false" (as a **string**).

I would like it to be a **raw boolean value**, so, back into my javascript client code, I could do

```
if (result.data) {
  // do something if the result is true ...
}
```

Because now, I have to do this ugly thing :

```
if (result.data == "true") {
}
```

I get the result from my custom "userService" service :

```
userService.isCodeValid($scope.code).then(function (result)
{
    console.log(result);
});
```

And this is the code of the isCodeValid method in my userService :

```
angular.module('clockin').service('userService', ['$http',
    function ($http) {
        this.isCodeValid = function (code) {
            return $http.get("/lewis/production/clockin/iscodevalid?code=" + code);
        };
    }
]);
```

Any idea of what I am missing ?

Comment: Would you like it to *return* as a boolean, or would you like to *make it* one?

Comment: This is related to JSON parsing, define your type for `data` as `bool` and parsing should return you a bool, not a string.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I want my javascript code to see the value as a boolean value.

Comment: @Habib : The object is built by Angular's $http.Get method. I have no control over that. Can you give me an example ?

Comment: @JoanLeaven, how are you getting/parsing the JSON string to your object `result` ?

Comment: @Habib I have updated my question (look at the last section).

Comment: @JoanLeaven, that is not C# code, and I am not sure how it can be done in Angular. I didn't realize that your code `if (result.data == "true")` is from JS. I believe some other SO user could help you out here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSON is JS *Object* Notation.  You aren't returning an object, just a bool.  Without the server response body being wrapped in `{ .. }` the browser can only assume that this string it got from the server is in fact just a string.  Wrap your service response in an object and the bool property will be serialized as a bool.

You don't even need to define a new class for this purpose:

```
[HttpGet]
public object IsCodeValid(string code)
{
    return new { result: db.Usagers.Any(u => u.CodeAcces == code) };
}
```

(then change the client side accordingly)

The alternative is to modify the JS to convert the string to a bool.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLevy. It works when I wrap the boolean value inside an anonymous object.

Comment: One thing I'd add is - it should be `result = ` not `result:`. Anyway many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just string data much like XML (just more compact). The result you're seeing is the raw result returned by the server. When you process that result through a JSON parser such as Newtonsoft.Json you will get the actual `bool` type as you expect.

Comment: You mean that I have to convert the resulting string into a boolean value once back into my client javascript code ? That would be ridiculous. What about datetime types ? I have to manually convert everything back to their corresponding data type ?

Comment: just call `JSON.parse` passing in the data result from the web call. You should get back a boolean type. This is pretty standard behavior for turning a JSON string into an object graph.

Comment: Thanks @RobEpstein. Parsing the result using JSON.parse is the working alternative to the two other answers which suggested to wrap the boolean value inside an object before returning it.

Comment: @JoanLeaven - I would personally avoid returning more data than is necessary (the result of wrapping the bool in an anonymous type). If possible try to use the `JSON.parse` solution to keep your network traffic minimal. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Move your element off the root by inserting an anonymous transport object as a parent:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public bool IsCodeValid(string code)
 {
     return new {isValid: db.Usagers.Any(u => u.CodeAcces == code)};
 }
```